# 'Graying Out' a WPF button image?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a simple `Button` control that contains an `Image` object as its content. I want so set the `Image` opacity to 0.5 when the `Button` is disabled to provide an additional visual cue as to the `Button` status.

What is the simplest way to accomplish that result in XAML? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Couldn't make this work. This worked for me:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532943/icommand-canexecute-can-not-disable-button-with-image-content/11126571#11126571

Answer (score 187, accepted):

Use a trigger in the Image style.  (It would be more natural to put it in the Button style, but the Button style can't easily affect the Image for annoying technical reasons.  It *could* be done in the Button's ControlTemplate but that's overkill for what you want here.)

```
<Button>
  <Image Source="something.png">
    <Image.Style>
      <Style TargetType="Image">
        <Style.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5" />
          </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
    </Image.Style>
  </Image>
</Button>
```

Note we are taking advantage here of the fact that the Image will be disabled when the Button is disabled, so we can trigger directly on the Image's own IsEnabled property.  In other cases, the Button property we want to trigger on might not be inherited by the Image; in that case, we'd need to use a DataTrigger with the FindAncestor RelativeSource to bind to the containing button.

Comment: FWIW, when using XAML images in a ControlTemplate, you can add this to the `<Viewbox.Style>`. I used this to make toolbar buttons fade when disabled.

Comment: Just want to point out that, more than 13 years later, the trigger appears to work properly if applied directly to the button style.

Answer (score 43):

If you want something more generic, put this in your resources section for your window or UserControl .

```
<UserControl.Resources>     
    <Style x:Key="ImageEnabled" TargetType="Image">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.25"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

And in the actual button just do this

```
<Button>
    <Image Source="{StaticResource LinkImage}" Style="{StaticResource ImageEnabled}"/>
</Button>
```

Comment: Replace `Source="{StaticResource LinkImage}"` with your actual code, e.g. `Source="Resources/stop-icon.png"`. It wasn't entirely clear to me on a first look. Also, I would argue that `ImageDisabled` is more semantically correct as the style's name. Otherwise, a very good answer.

Comment: Don't put x:Key="ImageEnabled" and it will apply to all images. A disabled image should always be grayed. Not only images in a button IMO.

Answer (score 23):

Here's a more generic style you can apply:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Image">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

Comment: Note that this only works if the Image is a direct child of button. In my case, the button content is wrapped by a StackPanel and didn't worked.

Comment: @JonePolvora thank you for clarifying. I was confused why I failed to benefit from this post until I saw your post.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the entire button greyed out, styling the button itself has worked for me. It seems to grey out all button content.

```
                    <Button.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="Button">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value=".75"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Button.Style>
```

Comment: This does work. Note however that it conflicts with use of an alternative theme (like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156199/wpf-options-classic-theme) such that the button seems to revert to a 2D look & feel vs. the "Classic" theme I was using.

Answer (score 2):

previous solutions only change opacity and not the color of the image, to gray out an image one need to convert the image to grayscale as follow. I did it for a toggleButton but the same method can be used on a button.

```
<ToggleButton>
    <ToggleButton.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
           <Setter Property="Content">
               <Setter.Value>
                    <Image
                         RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"
                         RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"
                         Source="/Resources/imageForButton.png"
                         Stretch="UniformToFill" />
                 </Setter.Value>
             </Setter>
             <Style.Triggers>
                 <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                     <Setter Property="Content">
                         <Setter.Value>
                             <Image
                               RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"
                               RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"
                               Stretch="UniformToFill">
                                 <Image.Source>
                                    <FormatConvertedBitmap
                                       x:Name="myImageFormat"
                                       DestinationFormat="Gray8"
                                       Source="/Resources/imageForButton.png" />
                                 </Image.Source>
                             </Image>
                       </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
             </Trigger>
          </Style.Triggers>
       </Style>
    </ToggleButton.Style>
</ToggleButton>
```