# Button using ICommand does not get disabled?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, icommand, canexecute

I have a button control in my wpf-mvvm application.

I use an `ICommand` property (defined in viewmodel) to bind the button click event to viewmodel.

I have -> execute and `canexecute` parameters for my `ICommand` implementation (`RelayCommand`).

Even if `CanExecute` is false...button is not disabled...WHEN button CONTENT is IMAGE

But, when button content is text..enable/disable works fine.

```
<Button DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
                        Command="{Binding Path=MoveUpCommand}">
                    <Button.Content>
                        <Image Source="/Resources/MoveUpArrow.png"></Image>
                    </Button.Content>
                    <Style>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value=".5" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Button>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Button does get disabled, its just that it doesn't affect rendering of the image.
You will have to write a trigger in the style which changes the opacity of the image to .5 and you'll get the desired effect of button disabled like so:

```
<Style x:Key="imageButton" TargetType="Button">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value=".5" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Do I have to declare a property "IsEnabled" in viewmodel ?..Or will it take that value by default from the canExecute ?

Comment: IsEnabled is the property of button that changes automatically when you return false from CanExecute

Comment: I have tried what you told me..It's giving some issues..please see the code available in my question above.

Comment: I got the cause of err. I was using more then two tems inside content. Thanks alot.

Comment: It would be nice to show how this plugs into the button for those of us who are not so good at WPF.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks! Tried the suggested code after all my buttons. Didn't work. Tried to extract just the trigger and insert it in a generic button that all other buttons inherited from: worked like a charm! This code first:

```
<Style x:Key="SecButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,5,5" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value=".5" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Based on the code above I created buttons like this:

```
<Style x:Key="NewBtnStyle" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource SecButton}">                
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="Images/new.png" Width="50" Height="50" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

When buttons where disabled the images in them is automatically dimmed to 0.5 opacity.

Answer (score 0):

You will need [pixel shader effect](http://bursjootech.blogspot.com/2008/06/grayscale-effect-pixel-shader-effect-in.html) (it is not as complicated as it sounds, it's just about adding an assembly reference an then you can use it as easily as any in-built WPF effect) in conjunction with trigger similar  to the one Hasan Khan posted to show the disabled button images in grayscale.

Comment: Surely using a [FormatConvertedBitmap](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/317/Default.aspx) to convert to gray scale would be more straightforward than a pixel shader!

Comment: And that can be done from XAML? Also, pixel shader can handle anything, not just bitmaps. And can be applied application-wide without touching the controls. And is calculated on the GPU (unlike FormarConvertedBitmap), letting CPU and RAM concentrate on more important stuff.

Comment: Yes, that can be done pretty much from xaml: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.formatconvertedbitmap%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. Also, compiling the pixel shader requires a 500+ MB download of the DirectX SDK, involves a different coding language in HLSL, .fx and .ps files. So while I still want to get into pixel shaders some illuminated day, my vote clearly goes to FormatConvertedBitmap for ease of implementation. Here's what I ended up with: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25511558/385995

Comment: @adabyron You don't need any of that. The link I posted provides an assebly with a ready-to-use shader. Just ref the assembly and use the effect from XAML, no other code needed.

Comment: @MatějZábský I avoid additional (unmanaged) dependencies whenever I can, and keep code I might want to change inside my project. But if you're sure that's exactly what you need then I'm sure this pre-compiled shader in an assembly is a sensible solution as well.